# rsync parallel vs serial transmissions

Tags: bash, shell, rsync

Using Bash 4 and rsync on RHEL 6, are there any differences between the following methods?  If so, which is more efficient, and what are the differences between these 3 methods:

```
1) rsync -avz /files/* user@remote_server:/remote_files
2) for file in /files/*; do rsync -avz $file user@remote_server:/remote_files;done
3) for file in /files/*; do screen rsync -avz $file user@remote_server:/remote_files;done
```

I am looking for information pertaining to what will transmit the fastest, given the same server.  What if there is a low number of large files, vs a large number of small files?  Does that matter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I am looking for information pertaining to what will transmit the fastest, given the same server.

There should not be any significant difference because [the bottleneck](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bottleneck) is the network speed.

In other words, while #3 might be discussed in relation to #1 and #2 as introducing the possibility of parallelism (I'm not familiar enough with `screen` to say, but if it goes to the background and executes `rsync`, it would), this won't matter to the ultimate time required.  If the bandwidth between you and your destination is limited to 3 MB/s, then it doesn't matter whether in any given second one process accounts for all of it, or 10 parallel process each use some portion: you will still be syncing at 3 MB/s.

WRT #2 (and #3 if screen does not fork itself), unless you background `rsync` in the `for` loop (with `&`), you are syncing each file *in sequence*, so there is no possible parallelism or advantage.

Comment: I agree in general, and I think that #2, #3 should incur a slight loss for connection setup/handshake/teardown on network levels 4 and up (TCP handshake, window negotiation, rsync/ssh handshakes), right?

Comment: @UlrichSchwarz I guess so, although I don't think it will be that noticeable unless this is involves lots of tiny files.  Without forking and parallelism, really #1 is the only sane method, and over a network that's probably true even with forking and parallelism.